# Minimize/Maximize both the screens

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-monitors

I have an application which runs on 2 monitors (say Primary screen and Secondary screen). The secondary screen does not have the control box property set to it. It depends completely on the functionality of the primary screen. What I am not able to figure out is, if I minimize the primary screen to the system taskbar, I need to minimize the secondary screen too. Also as soon as I maximize the primary, the secondary should also be maximized.

**UPDATE**
I tired to do something like this, but messed it up. It creates 2 forms as soon as the application starts which I do not want.

```
private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SecondaryLayoutForm secondaryLayoutForm = new SecondaryLayoutForm();
     if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
     {
         secondaryLayoutForm.Hide();
     }
     else
     {
         secondaryLayoutForm.Show();
     }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a reference to the secondary screen's Form?  If so, you could look at manipulating the WindowState property.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/winforms/thread/4600B962-3A77-4195-91FC-D016F626CE04

Comment: I do have the reference to the secondary screen but not in the primary screen form. The secondary screen will be instantiated in another class only if some values are met. So basically I do not have the ref of sec screen in my primary screen

Comment: You could create a minimized/maximized event on the primary form that the secondary form subscribes to.

Comment: Thats what I want to know :). I tried to create a Resize event on primary form, but messed it up.                                 private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SecondaryLayoutForm secondaryLayoutForm = new SecondaryLayoutForm();
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                secondaryLayoutForm.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                secondaryLayoutForm.Show();
            }
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, on your MainForm class:

```
private SecondaryLayoutForm secondaryLayoutForm;

private void MainForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (this.secondaryLayoutForm == null)
   {
      this.secondaryLayoutForm = new SecondaryLayoutForm();
   }

   // replace the 'this.ShouldShowSecondaryForm()' call with whatever 
   // your special condition is for showing the secondary form.
   if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized && this.ShouldShowSecondaryForm())
   {
        this.secondaryLayoutForm.Show();
   }
   else
   {
        this.secondaryLayoutForm.Hide();
   }
}
```

This makes the MainForm responsible for creating your SecondaryLayoutForm and controlling its window state - if you don't want that, then consider creating a UIManager class or something to separate this out.

**Update**

A sample app I wrote with 2 forms.  This is what's in Form1, Form2 just has a text box on it so it's visibly different to Form1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Form2 f2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(Form1_Resize);

        // Initialize Form2 
        f2 = new Form2();
    }

    void Form1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       // whenever I change the size of Form1, make sure 
       // Form2 has the same WindowState
       f2.WindowState = this.WindowState;
    }

    // This is your condition to either show or hide the form.
    //
    // Rather than a checkbox, have something that will respond to whatever 
    // condition you have set out - probably an event on another class.
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            f2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            f2.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:  Example of how to do this from a different class**

```
public partial class UIManager
{
    private Form2 f1;
    private Form2 f2;
    private bool shouldShowForm2 = false;

    public bool ShouldShowForm2 
    { 
       get { return shouldShowForm2; }
       set { shouldShowForm2 = value;  OnShouldShowForm2Changed(); }
    }

    public UIManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Initialize Forms
        f1 = new Form1();
        f2 = new Form2();
        f1.Resize += new System.EventHandler(f1_Resize);
        f1.Show();
    }

    void f1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
       // whenever I change the size of Form1, make sure 
       // Form2 has the same WindowState
       f2.WindowState = f1.WindowState;
    }

    // This is your condition to either show or hide the form.
    private void OnShouldShowForm2Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ShouldShowForm2)
        {
            f2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            f2.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

However, whether you do this from one of the forms or a separate class, something will need a reference to both forms so it can synchronize the window states.

Comment: This is similar to what I have done. I understand you declaring the secondaryLayoutForm outside. But when the application loads for the first time, the secondaryLayoutForm will always be null. So a blank form opens up which i do not want.

Comment: Ok, I created a sample that does the right thing as far as making sure the secondary window copies the primary window.  You'll want to change the check, and you might want to separate this code out somewhat if you don't want the secondary window to be controlled by the primary one.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely is one of the approaches to the problem. But unfortunately in our design, the main form doesnt have access to the secondary form at all. It is completely hidden from the user. But I am sure this definitely works as a generic example, so I will accept this solution.

Comment: Cool :) Yeah this is a generic example.  Do you have another class that manages whether SecondaryForm should be shown / minimized etc and **has a reference to both forms**?  If so, you should move your MainForm.Resize event handler into that class.  That just seemed like a more heavyweight example though.

Comment: I have an application manager class which manages MainForm and another LayoutGrid class. The secondary form is present in the LayoutGrid class as I want to hide this class from the user. It should just look like 1 window which pops up for certain projects. So what I will have to do is in the LayoutGrid I will have to access the Application Manager's form and take care of it which I have done right now. But was looking for a different approach.

Comment: Ok, I added another example of how you'd do this from another class.  Ultimately, whatever class is doing this work will need a reference to both forms.

Comment: @Vinay let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2532/discussion-between-johnl-and-vinay)

Comment: Hey John, i jut implemented the Publish/subscribe and it works .. Thanks :)